# Aurelia Dynamically Bound Value Converter

Tags: aurelia

I'm running into an issue with Aurelia and am assuming that there is something I am missing.

I'm trying to create a 'generic' grid. I have removed a lot of the html to keep the example short, but the basic idea is this:

```
<template>
<require from="../value-converters"></require>
  <table show.bind="rows.length">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th repeat.for="columnDefinition of columnDefinitions">
          ${columnDefinition.displayName}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr repeat.for="row of rows">
        <td repeat.for="columnDefinition of columnDefinitions">
          <span if.bind="columnDefinition.isCurrency">${row[columnDefinition.propertyName] | numeralFormatter}</span>
          <span if.bind="columnDefinition.isDate">${row[columnDefinition.propertyName] | dateFormatter}</span>
          <span if.bind="!columnDefinition.isCurrency && !columnDefinition.isDate &&">${row[columnDefinition.propertyName]}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

I want to be able to use the ValueConverters to help properly display certain types of column data. The above is currently working, but I want to have more value converters for other columns and the conditions will get unwieldy. My experience with Aurelia so far is that it offers fairly elegant solutions, but I have been unable to figure this one out as of yet.

I tried adding another property to the columnDefinition class like this `formatter:string = undefined` and then tried to create the spans like the following:

```
<span if.bind="columnDefinition.formatter">${row[columnDefinition.propertyName] | columnDefinition.formatter}</span>
<span if.bind="!columnDefinition.formatter">${row[columnDefinition.propertyName]}</span>
```

but the parser threw an error on the '.'.

Is there any way to achieve this? What is the 'aurelia-way' of dealing with this type of a problem.

Thanks in advance for any help that could be offered.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up taking a similar approach to the one suggested by [@Slyvain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121445/sylvain) with a bit of a different twist:

```
import {DateValueConverter} from './date';
import {NumberValueConverter} from './number';
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@autoinject()
export class MetaValueConverter {
    constructor(private date: DateValueConverter,
                private number: NumberValueConverter) {
    }

    public toView(value, valueConverter, format) {
        /* JUSTIFICATION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898440/aurelia-dynamically-bound-value-converter#comment-65199423 */
        /* tslint:disable:no-string-literal */
        if (this[valueConverter] && this[valueConverter].toView) {
            return this[valueConverter].toView(value, format);
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public fromView(val, valueConverter, format) {
        if (this[valueConverter] && this[valueConverter].fromView) {
            return this[valueConverter].fromView(value, format);
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Original code can be found [here](https://github.com/PdUi/skeleton-typescript-aspnet/blob/master/AspNetApp/app/src/value-converters/meta.ts).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks fantastic! Thanks so much for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

I followed [@peinearydevelopment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874522/peinearydevelopment) and went one step further again to create a fully dynamic value converter.

Usage is as follows `${myValue | dynamic:converterKey:converterArgs}` or simply `${myValue | dynamic:converterKey}` if no additional arguments are required. The `converterKey` is used to request a value converter that should be registered with the container. `converterArgs` is the array of arguments that you'd pass to the `toView` & `fromView` functions.

```
import { autoinject, Container } from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

export type ValueConverterKey = new (...args: any[]) => object;

type ValueConverterFunc = (...args: any[]) => any;

interface ValueConverter {
  toView?: ValueConverterFunc;
  fromView?: ValueConverterFunc;
}

@autoinject()
export class DynamicValueConverter {
    constructor(
      private container: Container,
    ) { }

    public toView(value: any, converterKey?: ValueConverterKey, ...converterArgs: any[]) {
      if (!converterKey) {
        return value;
      }

      return this.convertValueIfPossible(value, converterKey, converterArgs, 'toView');
    }

    public fromView(value: any, converterKey?: ValueConverterKey, ...converterArgs: any[]) {
      if (!converterKey) {
        return value;
      }

      return this.convertValueIfPossible(value, converterKey, converterArgs, 'fromView');
    }

    private convertValueIfPossible(value: any, converterKey: ValueConverterKey, converterArgs: any[], func: keyof ValueConverter) {
      let converter = this.container.get(converterKey);

      if (converter) {
        let converterFunc = converter[func];

        if (converterFunc) {
          return converterFunc.call(converter, value, ...converterArgs);
        }
      }

      return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW we had a use-case where we created a package containing a custom element that displayed a value however we wanted to provide the ability for users of the package to convert the displayed value as required.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a single `<span>` with a single general purpose converter that takes the column definition as a parameter and that delegates to the right converter? I think that would make the component markup simpler.

```
<span>${row[columnDefinition.propertyName] | formatCell:columnDefinition}</span>
```

And inside the formatter:

```
export class FormatCell {
  toView(value, columnDefinition){
    if(columnDefinition.isCurrency)
        return new CurrencyConverter().toView(value);

    if(columnDefinition.isDate)
        return new DateConverter().toView(value);

    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I could definitely do that, but if I then came up with another type converter, say I had an enum and I wanted to convert it to text, I couldn't just create the converter and columnDefinition and have it just work, I'd have to add another if statement here. It doesn't seem ideal for extensiblilty.

Comment: 1 - a new if statement each time or a new line in the markup each time are pretty close. 2 - You don't really need a new if statement each time. That was just to show that you can externalize the converter selection. You could have a convention `type + "Converter"` and create the converters dynamically. Or you could register named converters with the DI container at application startup and here in this converter ask the container for a converter of that name. If one is found you use it, otherwise you return `value`.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Did you find a different solution or is this the best approach?  I'm trying to do exactly the same thing right now and Sylvain's solution seems to be the best way to do it from my current perspective but I'm not as experienced with Aurelia as some other developers.

Comment: @LStarky. I have posted my approach below, it is similar to the one Sylvain suggested, but I think a bit more extendable. I would still be very interested in hearing different approaches from others.